# How can I drag and drop an item in a FlatList to outside the list?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

As you can see in the example snack link I shared below, when I want to drag an item in a FlatList out of the list, it works on iOS but not on Android. I added overflow visible for FlatList but it didn't help. Does anyone have any suggestions?

https://snack.expo.dev/q2dwoWdNR

As for my goal here, I want to create the puzzle game scene you can see in the attached screenshot in React Native.

[sample SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYtiU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for the issue. Here's a brief overview of my approach:

Shared Value Management: The offsetX, offsetY, and isDragging states are managed using useSharedValue.

Gesture Handling: The drag gestures are captured using Gesture.Pan(), which updates the offset values accordingly.

Dual Animated Styles:

The first (animatedStyles) moves the original box within the FlatList.
The second (dragOverlayStyle) is for the duplicate Animated.View, visible and moving only during the drag.

Rendering Components:

FlatList: Renders the draggable boxes.
Drag Overlay: Acts as a duplicate of the dragged item, moving freely across the screen.
This method effectively bypasses the overflow constraints on Android, allowing a seamless drag-and-drop experience across the entire screen.

I share the snack link below in case anyone is looking for a similar solution.

https://snack.expo.dev/seqjbrV7W